# The method 'readCounter' was called on null, even after using try catch while getting file from Local Storage in flutter

Tags: file, flutter, dart, local-storage

I wanted to store data in local file for persistence. So, I first tried the example given on flutter.dev and it worked on a separate project but when I implemented the same thing in the app I am working on, it is throwing an error and I cannot figure out why is it doing this. Initially the file is empty so the try catch statement should work and I tested it in the example project and it worked there but in this project it doesn't work.

Class for Local Storage

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class CounterStorage {
  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/counter.txt');
  }

  Future<int> readCounter() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localFile;

      // Read the file
      String contents = await file.readAsString();

      return int.parse(contents);
    } catch (e) {
      // If encountering an error, return 0
      return 0;
    }
  }

  Future<File> writeCounter(int counter) async {
    final file = await _localFile;

    // Write the file
    return file.writeAsString('$counter');
  }
}
```

initial State:

```
  CounterStorage storage;
  int _counter;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    storage.readCounter().then((int value) {
      setState(() {
        _counter = value;
      });
    });
  }
```

Error:

```
I/flutter ( 6380): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 6380): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building _BodyBuilder:
I/flutter ( 6380): The method 'readCounter' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 6380): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 6380): Tried calling: readCounter()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `readCounter` on a null object.

```
CounterStorage storage;
    int _counter;

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        storage = new CounterStorage(); // add this line
        storage.readCounter().then((int value) {
          setState(() {
            _counter = value;
          });
        });
      }
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked but how this (https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files) example is working without storage = new CounterStorage();

Comment: if you notice in the ``main()`` function: ``home: FlutterDemo(storage: CounterStorage()),``  CounterStorage class object is being passed.

and on the``state class of FlutterDemo``, ``storage`` variable is set

Comment: got it. Thanks for explaining it.